# Doctrine2 : preFlush getScheduledEntityInsertions() works but not getScheduledEntityUpdates()

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have some entities with abstract class: `EntityDated` wich mean that the entity contain 4 commons fields: `created`, `updated`, `created_by` and `updated_by`. I want update the 4 data when I create entity and update '`updated`' and '`updated_by`' when I update the entity.

I made a service calling my listener:

```
public function preFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $token = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();
        $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        // Inserts
        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
            if (is_subclass_of($entity, 'Kiwi\Bundle\TrainingBundle\Entity\EntityDated')) {

                $entity->setCreated(new \Datetime()); 
                $entity->setCreatedBy($token->getUser()->getUsername());
                $entity->setUpdated(new \Datetime()); 
                $entity->setUpdatedBy($token->getUser()->getUsername()); 

            }
        }

        // Updates
        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
            if (is_subclass_of($entity, 'Kiwi\Bundle\TrainingBundle\Entity\EntityDated')) {

                $entity->setUpdated(new \Datetime()); 
                $entity->setUpdatedBy($token->getUser()->getUsername()); 

            }
        }
    }
```

This works only for INSERTS not for UPDATES (changes are saved but updated and updatedBy stay the same). If i debug `$uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates()`, I see that it's empty. Why updated entities are not managed here?

Comment: Instead of looping through all the entities handled by the orm why don't you juste add your code for the inserts in the constructor of your abstract and use the preUpdate event for your updated fields?

Comment: Because I need to access to current User authenticated  (to set updated_by field) and it's impossible in the Entity context.

And I tried preUpdate(), it's works good but not with related entities.

Comment: You should be listening to onFlush (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush) not preFlush.  The change sets are not yet computed.  Be sure to recompute.

Comment: I tried onFlush but this is not the solution because of related entities are not managed. With preFlush it's working perfectly on insert. When I display $uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates(), i see empty array. This means that even if I recompute, this will not be handled because i work in my foreach().

So the problem is only with UPDATE wich is not working (but INSERT works).

Comment: preFlush is working as designed.  The manual is clear.  It's easy to track new entities which explains why insert works.  Determining which entities need updating requires computing a change set.  Something which is done between preFlush and onFlush.  Did you see the part about having to recompute the entities after changing them?

Comment: Might want to take a look here: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Timestampable/TimestampableListener.php

Comment: Thanks for your help, i did a preFlush() to handling INSERTS and a onFlush to handling UPDATES. This both operations work fine BUT when I DELETE a linked entity, it's correctly removed from the collection of the mother entity but the changes on mother entity are not saved. (Changes are saved if I create new linked entities or if I edit them).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to perform both Inserts and Updates I had to change two points :

- Use `onFlush()`, not `preFlush()`
- Add recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet() after each change

The new code :

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
{

    $token = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();
    $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    // Inserts
    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
        if (is_subclass_of($entity, 'Kiwi\Bundle\TrainingBundle\Entity\EntityDated')) {

            $entity->setCreated(new \Datetime()); 
            $entity->setCreatedBy($token->getUser()->getUsername());
            $entity->setUpdated(new \Datetime()); 
            $entity->setUpdatedBy($token->getUser()->getUsername()); 

            $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
            $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity);

        }
    }

    // Updates
    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        if (is_subclass_of($entity, 'Kiwi\Bundle\TrainingBundle\Entity\EntityDated')) {

            $entity->setUpdated(new \Datetime()); 
            $entity->setUpdatedBy($token->getUser()->getUsername());

            $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
            $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity); 

        }                
    }

}
```